# Java - Difficulty installing program from 3 separate .jar files (involves CLASSPATH)

Tags: java, installation, classpath, jar

I'm having a little trouble running some Java code, which requires three .jar files to be used. I'm at a lost as to what to do with them--I've tried setting the CLASSPATH (and following the instructions for how to do so in the readme files), but to no avail.

I was wondering if someone could walk me through it? I'd imagine three .jar files would be an easy install for someone who knows what they're doing.

If it helps, I'm using Ubuntu pretty much right out of the box (but I do have JDK and Eclipse installed!)

Runtime library: http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/download/software/20

Additional .jar needed: http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/download/software/23

Program I ultimately need to run: http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/download/software/26

If you're willing to help, I can't thank you enough--you deserve a million kudos!

G

Comment: Can you post any error messages you are getting?

Comment: And post the command you use to start the program. Nowadays setting the CLASSPATH environment variable is almost never needed

Comment: java -cp LBJ2.jar:LBJPOS.jar:LBJChunk.jar Main.class           
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main.class
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: Main.class.

Answer (score 1):

Those are all JAR files. When you execute a JAR file by doubleclicking or using `java -jar`, the `CLASSPATH` environment variable and the `-cp` and `-classpath` arguments are **ignored**. The classpath should be defninied in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file of the JAR. In this particular case, only the second and third JAR have a `Class-Path` entry in the manifest file:

```
Class-Path: LBJ2Library.jar
```

Which is the first JAR. The classpath is telling that it is expecting the `LBJ2Library.jar` to be in the **same folder** as the JAR you'd like to execute (either the second or third one).

So, just drop them all in the same folder and execute by `java -jar LBJPOS.jar`.

Comment: I got it working by combining all the .jar files into a single .jar. It works!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `java -jar` to run your jar files, then the CLASSPATH variable is ignored. If you are using `java -jar`, you have two options:

1. Combine the three jars into one jar.
2. Run the main class directory and don't use `-jar`.

Answer (score 0):

Use of the CLASSPATH environment variable is generally discouraged nowadays. This is how it's done (on Linux):

```
java -cp library1.jar:library2.jar:mainapp.jar <fully qualified name of main class>
```

Comment: So, since I have 3 .jar files, would I do:

Comment: java -cp library1.jar:library2.jar:library3.jar:mainapp.jar ?

Comment: Ohh, I see what you mean. java -cp library1.jar:library2.jar:mainapp.jar Main.class

Comment: When I do this, I get: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main.class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: Main.class. Program will exit.

Comment: @Georgina: the name of the class does not include the .class filename suffix, but it does possibly include a package prefix. "Main.class" would be interpreted as a class named "class" inside a package named "Main".

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the CLASSPATH .place all the 3 jars in a folder , name it as lib 
See below to set classpath

set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%:lib;